# Populating a Flex 4 TextArea with text via CF remoting

Tags: coldfusion, object, flex4, remoteobject

I want a web page to display song titles and associated lyrics. 
I have a coldfusion cfc which provides the Flex app with the data via a database query
providing two fields songTitle and songLyric. I have no problem displaying the data in a 2 column datagrid but I'm not clear how to reference just the songLyric in the TextArea text

TIA

```
        protected function dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
        {
            lyrics.getLyric("Blackpatch");
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:CallResponder id="getLyricResult" result=""/>
    <lyrics:Lyrics id="lyrics" fault="Alert.show(event.fault.faultString + '\n' + event.fault.faultDetail)" showBusyCursor="true"/>

</fx:Declarations>
<mx:DataGrid x="175" y="97" id="dataGrid" creationComplete="dataGrid_creationCompleteHandler(event)" dataProvider="{getLyricResult.lastResult}">
</mx:DataGrid>
<s:TextArea x="394" y="126" text="???"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I sorted it

text="{getLyricResult.lastResult[0].songLyric}"